# Laravel 4 IoC Container stand-alone usage

Tags: php, dependency-injection, laravel, inversion-of-control, containers

I'm using Laravel's IoC container to help with some dependency. So the

`$app = new Illuminate\Container\Container;`

works and check for dependency

However I'm curious about one thing

If I do:
`$object_a = $app->make('MyClassA');`
and `MyClassB` depends on `MyClassA`

`$object_b = $app->make('MyClassB');`

will it be using the properties of `$object_a` or will it make me one from scratch.

If its the later - is there anyway to straight make `$object_b` and `$object_a` so that it resolves with dependency BUT be common - or is that the whole point of 
`App::singleton` ?

Comment: `App::singleton` is the solution.

Comment: so $object_a = App::singleton('MyClassA'); and then $object_b = $app->make('MyClassB');

the object_b will be using the object_a's?